# Como retornar um campo composto em um dropdown pelo ASP CORE usando Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

original no model  = `ViewData["JobId"] = new SelectList(_context.Job, "JobId", "JobDay");`
Preciso junto com o JobDay, colocar o campo Job.Entity.EntityName, Job e Entity estão relacionadas e no contexto.
front end:  `<select asp-for="Team.JobId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.JobId"></select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing data:

```
var ListJobs = from j in _context.Job
                            .Include(k => k.Entity)
                            .OrderBy(k => k.Entity.EntityName)
                             select j;
```

Creating the View Controler:  `ViewData["JobId"] = new SelectList(ListJobs, "JobId", "JobDay", "Entity.EntityName", "Entity.EntityName");`

Creating the Client View:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Team.JobId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Team.JobId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.JobId"></select>
            </div>
```

Final Result:
[image: Grouped DropDown]